# error: incompatible types: Opiskelija cannot be converted to String

Tags: java

i have arraylist:

```
protected List<Opiskelija> opiskelijat = new ArrayList<>();
```

And i woould like to add String type to it. i get error such as:

```
error: incompatible types: Opiskelija cannot be converted to String
    for (String alkio : opiskelijat) {
```

ive tried to research but have not found solution

Comment: a String is not of type Opiskelija. It's that simple

Comment: You could make a `List<Object>`, but that would be more of a hack than anything else...

Comment: @Stultuske is there way to make it into that type?

Comment: No. You can create a String based on your object, but then you would need a List<String>

Comment: Your code doesn't seem to be adding anything, you're trying to iterate your students (but as Strings, which they're not).

Answer (score 0):

add a toString() method to Opiskelija.java and call it while iterating:

```
for (Opiskelija opiskelija: opiskelijat) {
String asd = opiskelija.toString();
}
```

Comment: As I understood it, op wants to iterate through a list of this custom class and perform an action on a String representation of each object in it.

Though after reading the initial post of him again, I must admit this can be read in many ways.

Answer (score 0):

`List<Opiskelija> opiskelijat` can only hold objects that are of type `Opiskelija`. You can't add `String` type objects to it.

`for (String alkio : opiskelijat) { }` iterates over each item in `opiskelijat`, handling each one as a `String`. It fails to do so because of the aforementioned and that's why you get the error.

You can iterate through `opiskelijat` by `for (Opiskelija alkio : opiskelijat) { }` which will let you do stuff with each `Opiskelija` object one at a time. Every object in Java also has `toString()` method as they extend the base type `Object` that has it. You can call it on `Opiskelija` too (as in `opiskelija.toString()`) but it's likely not what you are looking for unless you have overridden the method in your class `Opiskelija`.

A bit more clarification is needed to give a helpful answer. What are you trying to achieve exactly?